# Create a barplot in R by a column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-visualization, bar-chart

For example, let the data frame, df, be

| Location | Snowfall |
| --- | --- |
| London | 0.4 |
| London | 1.3 |
| NYC | 4.3 |
| NYC | 0.2 |
| Paris | 3.0 |
| London | 2.0 |

Is there a way to make a bar graph of the total snowfall by location?

London's bar length would be 3.7 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can first `aggregate` and then use `barplot`.

```
barplot(Snowfall~Location, aggregate(Snowfall~Location, df, sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a `tidyverse` approach

### Data

```
df <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~Location, ~Snowfall,
   "London",       0.4,
   "London",       1.3,
      "NYC",       4.3,
      "NYC",       0.2,
    "Paris",         3,
   "London",         2
  )
```

### Plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


df %>% 
  #Grouping by Location
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  #Sum of Snowfall by Location
  summarise(Snowfall = sum(Snowfall)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Location,Snowfall))+     
  geom_col(width = .5)
```

[image]